# Excel - Return value of adjacent cell (which has the highest value)

Tags: excel, cell

I'm trying to write a formula to give me the value of a cell which is directly adjacent to that of the highest value within a range. For reference (https://gyazo.com/67e28d9427021c52731f56f72700aaf2) I want to return the name directly above the highest value (between C8 and F8) into cell H8. I've tried both HLOOKUP and VLOOKUP, a combination of Index and Match, but all to no avail.

*In most cases there is one number value greater than the rest, but since this has a tied result, I wanted to display both names if possible*

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: I have an answer about top 5 that will help you with this, have a search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=INDEX(C7:F7,1,MATCH(MAX(C8:F8),C8:F8,0)) will give you what you need however where two or more people have the same value (which is the highest), it will only return the first name.

You could however add in a COUNTIF to check this (ie COUNTIF in the array the number of values which equal to the max value) and then add further formula to handle this to then return two or more names where multiple people have the highest value...

Comment: The formula works fine for 90% of stored results, so I can do a quick manual check for any tied results. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify whether you want to return multiple names when two names align with the highest value?  If you just want to go in order from left-to-right whenever there's multiple matching max values you can use:

=INDEX(C7:F7,XMATCH(MAX(C8:F8),C8:F8,0,1))

The INDEX function returns the name based off of the result of XMATCH.  XMATCH here is finding the location of the max value within the array.

To check if there are multiple names that have tied max values you can use =COUNTIF(C8:F8,MAX(C8:F8)).  You would embed the initial formula into an IF statement such as =IF(COUNTIF(C8:F8,MAX(C8:F8))>1,"Tied Max Score",INDEX(C7:F7,XMATCH(MAX(C8:F8),C8:F8,0,1))).

If you want the result of your formula to return multiple names you'll need to use an array formula.  There are several other posts on this site that answer how to do that.

Comment: So I'd ideally have a formula that can handle when the highest value is tied, and also when it isn't.

Also I tried your formula for when there is a clear highest value and isn't working

Comment: Can you provide more details on what about it "isn't working" for you?  What result are you getting?

Comment: It was giving me the error #NAME!, however another answer in this thread provided a formula that returns the name if there is 1 value higher than the rest - so I got that sorted at least